# Do we need Jack to use Java 8 features to make a build using Android.mk?

Tags: android, java-8, rx-java, android.mk, android-jack-and-jill

I have an Android.mk file and I was trying to make a build for Android 8.1 where I was using RxJava but while building it, I was getting the error

```
Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled
```

so, I searched a lot and found that

```
"ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK:=false"
```

fixes the issue but I want to know how and why it is like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on https://source.android.com/setup/build/jack that Jack supports Java programming language 1.7 and lambda(in rxJava) is 1.8 feature so is it causing the problem? That is why I need to disable the compilation?

Comment: Please only use the answer text field if you really want to answer the question. Otherwise please use the link `Add a comment` below the question.